# How to stop Spring Boot autoconfiguring a JndiConnectionFactory when it's not needed

Tags: spring-boot, jndi

I have a Spring Boot app that can run under two profiles, the default one which is what is used when it runs under an app server with JMS message queues available via JNDI, and an alternative profile that uses embedded JMS queues (no JNDI involved).

For my default profile I have entries like this:

```
@Profile("default")
public class JmsConfigurationJNDI {


    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/InboundAsynchronousQueue")
    private Destination inboundAsynchronousQueue;
```

for my embedded profile I have this:

```
@Profile({"local"})
public class JmsConfigurationLocal {

    @Inject
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate inboundAsynchronousQueueTemplate () {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName("inboundAsynchronousQueue");
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
```

The issue I have is that I need to set 
spring.jms.jndi-name for my **default** config like so:

```
spring:
  jms:
     jndi-name: jms/__defaultConnectionFactory
```

But I don't want that set at all for my other profiles, because if it is set *JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration* goes off and configures a *JndiConnectionFactory* which I don't want.

So how can I say that my alternative profile doesn't contain a property that is specified in the default, without having a separate JNDI specific profile rather than a default profile that happens to be the one that supports a JNDI connection factory ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using application-{profile}.properties to do the above? In other words, application-default.properties containing your configuration for jndi-connection factory details.

See link to [spring-boot-features-external-config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

An excerpt to the above link:

> Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Properties are considered in the following order:
>
> ...
>
> 12) Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
>
> 13) Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)

Comment: I already have the default property in my default profile. What I want is a second profile to replace the property held in the default profile with a missing property.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand totally. I was thinking that you'd have 2 property files i.e. application-default.properties and application-local.properties where spring.jms.jndi-name property is defined inside your application-default.properties but not inside application-local.properties. When spring.profiles.active=default, then it only runs loading only application-default.properties and vice-versa when set with spring.profiles.active=local. I'm assuming you run exclusively either profile and not both.